# Scraping a table from webpage with Python

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup, html-table

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

player_code = open("/Users/brandondennis/Desktop/money/CF_Name.txt").read()
player_code = player_code.split("\r")


for player in player_code:

html =urlopen("https://www.capfriendly.com/players/"+player+"")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for section in soup.findAll('div',{"class": "table_c"}):
    table = section.findChildren()[10].text
    print player, table
```

Here is a link to a sample player page : https://www.capfriendly.com/players/patrik-elias

Here is a sample of player names that I am adding from a text file to the base url.

[image]

[image: This is ultimately What I am wanting to do for my text file of 1000+ players]

This is ultimately what I am wanting to do for my text file of 1000+ players

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you are expecting?

Comment: @keatinge I would like to eventually have them in csv format like the table formatted in on the website. [link](https://www.capfriendly.com/players/patrick-kane). I have a list of about 1000 names that I would like to get.

Comment: What table do you want?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I would like to get everything back to 2007-08. At the moment I am just trying to get the code to work for any table with salary information.

Comment: Add a Sample of your file, exactly as you see it.

Comment: I actually meant you file of players, exactly as you see it in an editor or what .read returns

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have found a code that gives me the full table that I want, but it is all in one. Is there a way to split this by year?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what the others mentioned. Take a look at this line:

```
table = soup.findAll('table_c')[2]
```

here, `BeautifulSoup` would try to locate `table_c` elements. But, `table_c` is a class attribute:

```
<div class="table_c"><div class="rel navc column_head3 cntrct"><div class="ofh"><div>HISTORICAL SALARY </div><div class="l cont_t mt4">SOURCE: The Hockey News, USA Today</div></div></div>
    <table class="cntrct" id="contractinsert" cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Use the `class_` argument instead:

```
table = soup.find_all(class_='table_c')[2]
```

Or, you may get directly to the table by `id`:

```
table = soup.find("table", id="contractinsert")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer when there is almost no context in your question (What exactly isn't working and what exactly you are trying to scrape), but take a look at these lines:

```
first_columns.append(row.findAll('td'))[0]
third_columns.append(row.findAll('td'))[2]
```

Since `append` returns `None` these lines would raise an exception.

I believe they are meant to be:

```
first_columns.append(row.findAll('td')[0])
third_columns.append(row.findAll('td')[2])
```

Comment: I continue to see this error.


(u'2018-19', u'$2,750,000')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bd/Desktop/untitled-14.py", line 15, in <module>
    table = soup.findAll('table')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @denn9268 Update your question with the exact code you are executing and the exact error you are getting. This bit of code works for me: `from urllib import urlopen;
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup;

url = 'https://www.capfriendly.com/players/patrik-elias';
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url));

table = soup.findAll('table')[0]`

Comment: that works for me as well with one name. I am getting the Error code when I am trying to pull from multiple names. I have updated the code and a sample list of names.

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis and brackets look misplaced.

Does this do what you want ?

```
first_columns = []
third_columns = []
for row in rows[1:]:
    first_columns.append(row.findAll('td')[0])
    third_columns.append(row.findAll('td')[2])
```

Where I no longer insert all the td elements in each list and then select the [0] and [2] elements, discarded anyways.

Answer (score 0):

*It seems to work fine for one player at a time, but when I change to my text file of a list of players that where I am having trouble.* I think how you are parsing the file is the issue, if you have a player per line just iterate over the file object, stripping any whitespace:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
import csv

with open("/Users/bd/Desktop/testfolder/Player_Code_Test.txt") as f:
   for player in map(str.strip, f)    

     html =urlopen("https://www.capfriendly.com/players/".format(player))
```